# Clickstream data in BigQuery - filtering customDimensions and customEvents simultaneously

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery to perform analysis on the out of the box Google clickstream data. I am new to BigQuery and an intermediate when it comes to my use of SQL.

I have a custom dimension (index=6) that represents the store# a user has selected on our website.
I have a custom event (eventInfo.eventAction='product details') that is sent when a user views a product on our website.

The desired result, is a list of products viewed, by user, with the store a user had selected at the time of the product view.
The result I get from the below SQL is an empty table.

Any help our pointing me in the right direction is appreciated. Thank you

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId, visitId,
  hits.customDimensions.value,
  COUNT(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory) AS productViews
FROM
  [table] 
WHERE
  hits.customDimensions.Index = 6
  AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'product details'
GROUP BY
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  hits.customDimensions.value
ORDER BY
  productViews DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any help our pointing me in the right direction is appreciated
>   The result I get from the below SQL is an empty table.

Your query works for me as it is without any changes/fixes and returns non-empty result!
I would recommend you to explore your data - it might be not what you expect.
You can do this using Preview feature in Web UI